# React Native example (UIExplorer) building issue

Tags: gradle, react-native, gradlew

SOLUTION

I've overcome the issue by helps @LeoCavalcante. 
The problem is that when using `gradlew` word in the command console, it can be run directly. Because, when using `gradlew`, Windows console run `gradlew.bat`!

Don't try with cygwin (linux) bash command like `sh ./gradle :Exam...` or `sh gradle :Exam..` or `bash gradle :Exam...`

**Just use `gradlew :Examples:UIExplorer:android:app:installDebug`**

---

I couldn't build UIExplorer examples from the react-native official repo.

I use Windows and cygwin64.

I've set up both of SDK and NDK. Then cloned the repo and gave `npm install` command in the root directory of react-native which has been cloned just now. I added `local.properties` file which specifies the `sdk.dir` and `ndk.dir` paths.

When I try the `sh ./gradlew :Examples:UIExplorer:android:app:installDebug` command the console has given an output like the below;

[image]

When I try the command with `--debug` parameter then the console output becomes too long. But the error lines like the below;

```
08:07:50.341 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Running model element 'tasks.validateDebugSigning' rule action Project.<init>.tasks.validateDebugSigning()
08:07:50.347 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Mutating tasks.validateDebugSigning using Project.<init>.tasks.validateDebugSigning()
08:07:50.354 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks.validateDebugSigning' to state ProjectionsDefined.
08:07:50.389 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
08:07:50.402 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
08:07:50.409 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
08:07:50.414 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
08:07:50.420 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Task '.' not found in root project 'react-native'.
08:07:50.425 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
08:07:50.429 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
08:07:50.436 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
08:07:50.443 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
08:07:50.449 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
08:07:50.456 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
08:07:50.461 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 2 mins 25.343 secs
```

How I can overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It seams that grade thinks that the single option `:Examples:UIExplorer:android:app:installDebug` is a series of options.

Try running: `bash gradlew ":Examples:UIExplorer:android:app:installDebug"`

Comment: Thanks you very much Leo. However I had tried the command of `sh ./gradlew ":Examples:UIExplorer:android:app:installDebug"`. Unfortunately, the same result. I tried android-ndk-r11b and android-ndk-r10e. I guess nobody has achieved build the example on Windows, except you..

Comment: Please, try exactly how I mentioned, using `bash` instead of `sh` and without `./` before the file name.

Comment: Ok. I've removed the react-native directory. I run the command of `npm install` right now :) Then I try your advice.

Comment: Unfortunately Leo. Thanks anyway. It gives exactly the same error message. Do you remember your setup/build steps on Windows?

Comment: In fact, if you have the `UIExplorer.apk`, it is useful for me. And of course if you available.. (I have to install the app to my phone and try the geolocation screen)

Comment: I'm not using Cygwin. Have you tried on a regular cmd/powershell terminal? I'm building it right now.
(SS)

Comment: Yes the problem was that :) Thank you. I run the command and turn the page to let you know. Thanks for taking your time. Could you please edit your answer by removing `bash` word next to `gradlew`.

Comment: Good to know it is working, but why you ask to remove `bash`? I just build version 0.23, like I did for 0.22. Since it's a bash script nothing better to run with bash, right?

![SS](http://i.snag.gy/cN4aU.jpg)

Comment: When using `bash gradlew...` or `sh gradlew..` the command returns the above error which İs my main question. If you doesn't correct your answer by removing bash word, someone else try bash command that is in your answer because of I accept the answer. Anyway. Thanks again..